# Python ( PIL ) '<_io.BufferedReader' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, image-processing, python-imaging-library

***specs***

- ubuntu 18.04 ( VPS )
- django
- python 3.8

**Error:**

```
File "/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2931, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BufferedReader name='/django/wall/media/wallpaper.jpg'>
```

this error occurred while I was processing an image with help of Django-imagekit

i m processing 1000's of images but this error occurs only on few, rest works fine

Comment: It's not a valid image file, apparently.  Have you tried viewing that file with any other software?

Comment: @jasonharper yeah, I viewed its a valid image of size 4.9 MiB